# Cart session count way too high for known traffic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, shopping-cart, cart

I have a Cart model that adds a row every time a user creates a new session.  I am getting less than 30 visitors a day (known from google analytics) currently, but for some reason my Cart.count increases almost 1,000 each day.

Could this be from the web crawlers accessing the site?

Comment: There could be any number of things causing that. Without seeing your code it is impossible to do a root cause analysis.

Comment: Ive just moved the code out of the application controller and create a new cart row when a user adds an item to the cart.  This way a new cart row isnt added every browser session or visit to the home page